# .bind('input', function(){}) not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I've been using `.bind('input')` with jQuery because it seems to best solution for detecting if they copy/paste into the box, or just type and then select from the browser given drop down menu. My problem with others such as `change()` is that, at least for me, they only trigger when the user's focus on the box is lost.

My problem is that `.bind('input')` doesn't work for me in IE8, yet works in Firefox 4/5. I have tried looking for alternatives to this but have come up empty. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried `.bind('keyup paste',function(){/*....*/});`?

Comment: That works for paste events, but I'm still not receiving a trigger when they select from the previous entries(I don't exactly know what it's called, but you know how browsers present you with a choice of previously entered choices)

Comment: @Nicholas It's autocomplete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete

Comment: That's the term I was looking for... thanks. I'm about to look up using that term, but is there any event trigger that'll do it in jQuery for autocompletes that's IE friendly(works it would seem in FF/Chrome, just not IE8)

Comment: FYI 'paste' in David's example doesn't work **if** using event delegation.  Apparently it doesn't bubble up properly in IE.  Ctrl+V is captured due to keyup, but right click+paste doesn't trigger the event.

Answer (score 10):

The `input` event is not supported below IE9. You can get more information about the `input` event here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php

I haven't tested yet, but this document says you can use a `onpropertychange` event instead.

Comment: onpropertychange doesn't trigger an event. But that's a good resource, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spicyj/jquery-splendid-textchange is a plug-in to fix the quirks of emulating "input" in IE8 and IE9.

The author described how he achieved this solution in his blog post (http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html), which is indeed complex, have a read if you want to know the details.