# jQuery bind input

Tags: jquery, input, bind

Before HTML5, we had to use the `onkeypress` event (or similar) to detect when a user adjusts the text in an input field. This often created synchronization problems and didn't work at all with on-screen keyboards, thus requiring us to bind multiple events. HTML5 solves this problem by defining the `oninput` event. Since HTML5 is not yet universally supported, however, it is often safer to use the `oninput` event *along with* the `onkeypress` event for backwards compatibility.

While writing a validation script, I recently discovered that the following works in jQuery:

```
$('input').bind('input', function() {...});
```

However, there seems to be very little documentation (if any) on this. My question is this: since this is implemented in jQuery (which should already be backwards compatible), is it necessary to include 'backup' events such as `onkeypress`?

I suppose there's nothing wrong with throwing a few extra bindings in:

```
$('input').bind('input keydown mousedown', function() {...});
```

but it would be nice to know whether or not the extra bindings are necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should think about backward compatibility because it's not supported in all browsers and for more information you can [**see here**](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php).

Comment: Right. I guess my question is actually about jQuery though. When I use the `input` binding through jQuery, does it take care of backwards compatibility?

Comment: Here is an answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669091/bindinput-function-not-working-in-ie8).

Comment: So it looks like even the jQuery version is not backwards-compatible. This surprises me, because several jQuery bindings are 'normalized' so that they work the same in all browsers. Oh well, I guess I'll be using multiple bindings...

Comment: I think multiple binding will be better. :-)